# How to save data in a user filled out form in android?

Tags: android

My app can access a registration form via the android activity. My question is, how to save it to a text file after a user filled data to the form? I want to save in the text file the data inputted by the user, for instance:

Address: User address here
City: User City
Province: User Province here
Zip: 4342343
Phone: 4534534534
What is your biggest regret in your life? None.

Comment: What type of form is this? And what do you mean with `via the android activity`?

Comment: yes it is an activity(a simple registration form) I need to store all those details in th form in my sd card

Comment: You still did not tell exactly how the form is build up/consists of.

Answer (score 0):

Text files are not the best solution when it comes to persist data. You have plenty of choices, being the most common of all:

- shared preferences
- android sqlite database

Some usefull links tho:

- [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)
- [SP StackOverflow example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example)
- [Android Sqlite StackOverflow example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015731/android-sqlite-example)

You didn't provide any details behind what you want to acquire. But if you really need to use text files, check @ojonugwa ochalifu link

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few references : 
[Store User Data Using Simple Text Files and APIs in Android](http://www.sitepoint.com/store-user-data-using-simple-text-files-and-apis-in-android/)

[Android Internal Storage: Read and Write text file example](http://www.androidinterview.com/android-internal-storage-read-and-write-text-file-example/)

[How to save text from an EditText as a table text file in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21828904/how-to-save-text-from-an-edittext-as-a-table-text-file-in-android)